# Make underline CSS transition change direction

Tags: html, css, underline

I am using some style I found on [this website](http://callmenick.com/post/simple-css3-transitions-transforms-animations-compilation) to create an underline slide in effect. Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juhL2256/) for example.
As you can see, the underline comes in from left to right. How would I go about making another line on top of the text, which transitions in from right to left? Could I simply adapt my current code snippet, or would I have to use a different method entirely?

```css
.cmn-t-underline {
  position: relative;
  color: #ff3296;
}
.cmn-t-underline:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #2E9AFE;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height:2px;
}
.cmn-t-underline:hover {
  color: #98004a;
}
.cmn-t-underline:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
 height:2px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="cmn-t-underline">Test</h1>
```

Comment: Nice. I guess it is something to do with transition type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/juhL2256/1/

Change left to right.

```
.cmn-t-underline:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #2E9AFE;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height:2px;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why it works, but it was the first thing I tried. I believe it's because the reference point is now starting from the right instead of the left and moves to it's 100% state on the left side.

Comment: Great, seems to work thanks! Is there a way to make this line displayed above the text?

Answer (score 3):

Try this , it work as you want

```css
.cmn-t-underline {
  position: relative;
  color: #ff3296;
}
.cmn-t-underline:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #2E9AFE;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height:2px;
}
.cmn-t-underline:hover {
  color: #98004a;
}
.cmn-t-underline:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
 height:2px;
}

.cmn-t-underline:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
 height:2px;
}

.cmn-t-underline:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #2E9AFE;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height:2px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="cmn-t-underline">Test</h1>
```

Comment: Why do people post the exact same answer 10 mins after another was already posted that solves the problem?

Comment: I do not know ;) .. when I answer the question I take time to try to solve problem in fiddle so I did not see your comments ... on the other hand my answer differant from you it draw to line above and below :)